# Showing a Specific Row From a Row Group - Visual Studio SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report in Visual Studio that displays students enrolled in a course. I am using a parameter to allow the user to include or exclude cancelled enrollments (there is a field in the source data that indicates whether an enrollment is cancelled or not).

When the user chooses to include cancelled enrollments, I am having trouble in the case of students who cancelled and then re-enrolled. This student would appear in 2 rows of data, but I would like only their most recent activity to appear (ie. if they enrolled, cancelled, then re-enrolled, I only want their latest enrollment to appear).

I currently have a Row Group expression set up to group by the student's unique identifier. However, I do not know how to control exactly which row determines the values for the other fields, when they have more than one row being grouped together.

My row grouping expression is as follows (where cf_code is the specific offering the student is enrolling in, and student_number is the student's unique identifier):

```
=Fields!cf_code.Value & Fields!student_number.Value
```

How can I indicate that when grouping cancelled and enrolled rows together for the same student, the only data that should be shown in the other fields in my matrix are the ones relating to the enrollment (the most recent activity)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you could potentially handle this:

1. If you only ever want to see the latest enrollment, you can eliminate these rows on the database side by doing a `MAX()`, partitioning on the student's unique identifier and ordering by the date. This may require passing your exclude parameter to the database so you don't exclude rows when you need them.
2. Using SSRS: in the student group you could set the row visibility expression to something like:

   `IIf(Count(enrollment_date) > 1, Max(enrollment_date) <> enrollment_date, False)`

This will check to make sure each row is the latest, and only display the row if it contains the latest enrollment date for that particular student.

Update: here's how I might group that. Start with a parent group on `student_number` whose child is the detail row group.

```
student_number
    [detail rows]
```

Then, on the detail row in the tablix (but not the student level), set the row visibility as described above. This separates the student from the enrollment and allows you to hide detail rows without the student disappearing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like to do this using SSRS if possible, so that all the data is still available for me to use. When I attempt your second suggestion, it seems to remove all of the rows for the particular student.

Comment: Oh oops. You'll want to wrap that in a `IIf` statement and only do the comparison when there's more than one row per student. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Chris: SSRS isn't well suited for manipulating data sets. Why not do it properly in the SQL?

Comment: @McGlothlin This still seems to hide the entire row group for a student. I suspect because by this point it has already grouped the rows together, and is then omitting them because the row grouping is displaying the data for the cancellation.

Comment: @Jacobm001 This is just one of several ways that this query can be filtered, based on user-defined parameters. That's why the dataset itself has to contain more information than this one specific case.

Comment: @Chris make sure you're setting the *row visibility* not the group visibility. Aside from that, it's hard to give more specific help without knowing your groupings. Could you edit your answer to include those?

Comment: @McGlothlin I've updated my question to include my row group expression. I only have one row grouping, so row visibility and group visiblity are the same, aren't they? When I change one, it changes the other.